# HTML Request Convert to Curl for Postman

Tags: html, api, curl, postman

I have the below code block but i am trying to rebuild this into a request in postman.

It is all the documentation has in order to build a request so i am looking for some advice of how to convert this into a useable postman request

```
<html>
<body onload="document.xml.submit();">
<form action=https://vcc-eu10.8x8.com/WAPI/wapi.php
method="post" name="xml">
<input type="hidden" name="xml_query"
value='<wapi>
<tenant>xxxxxx</tenant>
<username>xxxxxx</username>
<password>xxxxxx</password>
<command object="customer" action="get"> <firstname>Bill</firstname>
</command>
</wapi>'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a POST request to `https://vcc-eu10.8x8.com/WAPI/wapi.php`. The single parameter is named "xml_query" which contains the full `<wapi>...</wapi>` XML blob shown in the `<input>` tag's value.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank you for this. I was putting the <wapi> into the body, is that wrong?

Comment: I haven't used Postman in a while, but I'm pretty sure you'd set up your POST request with a single query param, with "xml_query" as the key, and the  full `<wapi>...</wapi>` xml blob as the value.  I'm not sure what you mean by "into the body".